# HTML - Why does input box have a box around it when selected

Tags: html, css, user-interface, input, border-radius

[image: This is what is the input box looks like when selected. I don't want the white square box showing up whenever I select it. I just want to see the curved input field.]

Hi,

I was making some HTML and CSS work and I encountered this issue regarding the html input tag which often comes up quite a lot. I use the CSS feature 'border-radius' to get a rounded input box. Despite this, whenever I select this white box appears, see attached image for detail. How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: set the outline to 0

Comment: Don't remove accessibility features people depend on.

Comment: @Quentin what do you mean by “accessibility features”?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus

Comment: @epascarello    please may you type your comment of 'set outline to 0' as an answer. This will make me able to accept it.

Comment: Impossible to add answers to closed questions.